# SharePoint 2013 Jan 2016 Updates

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

Is anyone here experience problems in SharePoint after installing the latest JAN 2016 on 13th Jan 2016 (Western Australian Time) updates for SharePoint 2013. I am guessing it could be KB3114503 update giving me problems.

I am getting the same problem on other machines after running the same updates too.

The problem I am receiving is, on every list view I get this error message below:

```
TypeError: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference  
TypeError: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null referenceSys.ArgumentNullException: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: element
```

Comment: I couldn't find anything from one of the SP updates engineer blog: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/01/12/january-2016-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/

Or Todd Klindt: http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Regressions/sp2013Jan2016cu.aspx

Comment: You should report it to Microsoft, or try to contact Stefan Grossner from the first blog with your issue.

Comment: Same errors here. This update breaks Sharepoint. There is no uninstall.

Comment: I'm facing the the same issue. However I can add a new list that is doing OK.
Unfortunately the particular update cannot be uninstalled. Guess I'll have to try to get the system back from tape .. BR Thomas

Comment: I can save with no issues, just after save and view the list the error appears.

Comment: Sent an email to Stefan Gossner about the issue. Hope there is a fix for this soon.

Comment: I think you should always apply N-1 cumulative update where N is the latest CU... otherwise we will end up with these sort of issues.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apply the Cumulative Update for SharePoint 2013 (Foundation, Server, or Project). This should resolve the issue. This appears to be caused from applying MS16-004 while having a previous Cumulative Update installed.

Cannot reproduce from a system upgraded to the SharePoint Server 2013 Jan 2016 CU, but can reproduce on another farm by only upgrading to MS16-004 with Sept 2015 CU applied.

EDIT: Stefan Goßner has also indicated it can be resolved by installing hotfix [KB3114508](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114508), also released on Tuesday 01/12/16.

Comment: Trevor Seward thanks this help solved the problem. All list view are back to normal.

Comment: Same here. Thanks! I keep forgetting CUs need to be installed manually and include additional fixes that Automatic Updates doesn't always deliver.

Comment: The hotfix KB3114508 mentioned by Stefan Goßner fixed this issue for us.

Comment: The hotfix KB3114508 worked for us as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Trevor now is there any prerequisites for installing the "KB3114508" ? now the latest updates done on our sharepoint farm was on November 2015,, and i do not want to apply additional updates for the time being as we have many tasks to do,, so is it safe if i install the KB3114508 ? even if i do not have the latest updates ??

Comment: @johnG The only pre-req is SP1, which is the currently minimum version required to receive support from Microsoft.

Comment: @TrevorSeward now i install the hotfix KB3114508, and my current farm build number is ​15.0.4763.1000? so do i need to run the product configuration wizard after i have installed the ​hotfix KB3114508,??

Comment: @TrevorSeward also i have a question if installing the hotfix KB3114508 will update the farm build number ? as my current build number is 15.0.4763.1000 which represents October 2015...

Comment: @johnG The farm build # will be 15.0.4787.1000. Yes, you must run psconfig/Config Wizard.

Comment: @TrevorSeward so in this case i need to apply this update to all our SharePoint servers (test, staging+live), i though this KB (hotfix KB3114508) is a minor hotfix but seems it will upgrade the farm build number,, so not sure if applying (hotfix KB3114508) is the same as applying the latest CU from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114497 ,, i am a bit confused ..as in my case i was on October 2015 CU (build number 15.0.4763.1000) and then i apply "hotfix KB3114508" which have updated my farm build number from October 2015 to Jan 2016 ,, seems wired to me. can you adivce please ?

Comment: @johnG Sorry I looked at the wrong patch. For KB 3114508, it should not update the build number as it does not include Microsoft.SharePoint.dll nor any schema extensions, as far as I can tell. That said, it should be applied to all servers in the farm and you'll still want to verify in Central Admin that the servers do not indicate a Upgrade Availability or Required.

Comment: @TrevorSeward but in my case i checked my farm build number it is now 15.0.4787.1000 ???so this hot-fix have updated my farm build number .. also i tried running the product configuration wizard and it failed and now i did a restart for the server but when i tried accessing my site collection i am getting blank pages !!!

Comment: @TrevorSeward will you be able to advice on this please? now after applying this (hotfix KB3114508) where i were on October 15.0.4763.1000 , the farm build number will be updated to  15.0.4787.1000 ,, and my site collection will be showing blank pages .. and when i tired accessing my site collection from "central administration">>" view all site collection", i can not see the site collections info such as site collection admin , content data base , url etc...

Comment: @johnG That issue is going to be unrelated to this thread. I'd suggest starting a new thread.

Comment: @TrevorSeward ok i wrote a new article http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169562/my-sharepoint-farm-stop-working-after-applying-a-hot-fix-kb-3114508

Answer (score 3):

We installed MS16-004 w/ KB3114503. Our error occurs on list items, and is often showing this "TypeError: b is undefinedTypeError: b is undefined...". We found that if the view was modified from "Item Text (linked to item with edit menu)" to "Item Text (linked to item)" the error would disappear and the user could see the list.

Not a complete fix, but could help someone seeing similar errors...

Comment: i am facing this problem also "TypeError: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null referenceTypeError ..nable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null referenceTypeError" and i chnage the column from title linked to edit menu to title linked to item , it will work ...

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, You have to wait to apply the CU, never rush into the installation. You have to install into the dev farm and then perform the testing. Once you sure that it is success then go for the production.

Did you apply the server CU or foundation? 
is it completed successfully( installation and config wizard)?
are you getting this error on all sites or few?

As a workaround [Mentioned in this post](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/219736), try to open the site in IE compatibility view.

Also, try contact MSFT about this.

Comment: The updates was installed on my work and home dev box. For work I can get the administrators to restore one of the VM backups. But for home unfortunately I have to re-create my VM again.

Comment: The post you provided doesn't fix the problem. But thanks for the help.

Comment: The question is about KB not a CU, the issue is resolved by appying a CU though!