# "TypeError: retString is undefined" error in all lists in a subsite

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

After installing Service Pack 1, in a subsite, all items in a list are not showing (`AllItems.aspx`) and for every item the following error is showing:

> TypeError: retString is undefined multiple times and 
>   Sys.ArgumentNullException: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be
>   null. Parameter name: element

Does anyone has a clue of what is that?

Comment: Are you using some custom JavaScript on the page, Client Side Rendering perhaps?

Comment: No, this site is a test site. I use it to test the migration from an xls file to sharepoint. The new items are made programmatically.

Comment: Looks same issue [SharePoint 2013 Jan 2016 Updates](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167034/sharepoint-2013-jan-2016-updates)

Comment: Did you run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard after applying SP1?

Comment: I guess. Microsoft did it!!! But' I'll check